# Strange behavior of the Evaluate function

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation

I am solving a system of differential equation whose unknown are saved under variable `vec={C00,C01,C10,C11}` and the solutions are saved under variable `sol`. However I observe a strange behavior using the `Evaluate` function.
If I do

```
Evaluate[#[t] /. sol] & /@ vec
```

I get

```
{{C00[t]},{C01[t]},{C10[t]},{C11[t]}}
```

That does not allow me to plot the function whereas if I do

```
1*Evaluate[#[t] /. sol] & /@ vec
```

I obtain an InterpolatingFunction that allows me to plot the function

```
{{2 InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t]},{2 InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t]},{2 InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t]},{2 InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},<>][t]}}
```

I would like to understand what happened here and why the function behave differently in these two cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on the `Evaluate` help page (Possible Issues section):

> Evaluate works only on the first level, directly inside a held function:

Your first version -when used with `Hold`- looks like this:

```
Evaluate[#[t] /. sol] & /@ vec // Hold // FullForm
```

> Hold[Map[Function[Evaluate[ReplaceAll[Slot[1][t],sol]]],vec]]

The second function:

```
1*Evaluate[#[t] /. sol] & /@ vec // Hold // FullForm
```

> Hold[Map[Function[Times[1,Evaluate[ReplaceAll[Slot[1][t],sol]]]],vec]]

As you can see, `Evaluate` has gotten a level deeper and is therefore not effective anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit subtle. I assume that your sol is something like

```
sol={{x->3}}
```

Evaluate is used to overrule an Hold attribute (not for evaluating expressions). The command Function has attribute HoldAll. So in your first situation you map

```
Function[ Evaluate[#[t] /. sol]]
```

(* {#1[t]}& *)

In the second situation, Evaluate is in a Times expression, so it has no effect on Function. So you map

```
Function[Times[1, Evaluate[#[t] /. sol]]]
```

(* 1 Evaluate[#1[t]/. sol]& *)